# Is it possible to mask dns queries?

Tags: dns, query, mask

Would it be possible to mask dns queries?

Example scenario : In a corporate network, can an end user machine mask it's dns queries as coming from another machine id.

Thank you.

Comment: Also, if this is possible, can i trace it back to the initial machine anyway?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

> can an end user machine mask it's dns queries **as coming from another machine id**

Usually that's not called masking, that's address spoofing. Masking would usually mean making the DNS queries *themselves* look like something that's not DNS (e.g. through encryption). In your case they're still clearly DNS queries.

Anyway – If the intent is to trick the corporate admins, and if you're talking about another machine *in the same network*, then it's both a yes and a no:

- Yes, it is possible to send queries with a fake source IP address. In many networks (depending on switch-level security), it might be very difficult to tell the difference.
- No, your machine will not be able to *actually use* DNS this way – it will not receive responses to those fake queries because they'll get delivered to the other machine instead. So you cannot use this method to bypass tracking for yourself, only to incriminate somebody else.

Managed Ethernet switches usually have features to prevent local IP spoofing (e.g. IP-MAC binding, sticky MAC, etc.) but those need to actually be enabled in order to work, and it doesn't help when both machines are still behind the same unmanaged switch.

Comment: Hi Grawity, thank you for responding.

Given that in a corporate network, the end user machines are on dynamic ips, faking the IP wouldn't change the machine name / ID right?

Comment: In this scenario, it's dns queries to made for a malicious site from random machines.

Comment: If you put it that way: DNS queries do not contain the machine's name / ID in the first place... they _only_ contain its IP address (and within the subnet, also the MAC address).